# Google+ on Android progress indicator style?

Tags: android, android-widget

The Android Google+ app (and possibly other standard system apps) have this nice circle indicator, that is styled very thin and looks as if two circles run against each other.

When I use one of the `@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar` styles for my own `<ProgressBar>` instance, I get a rather thick circle with a simple, unidirectional animation.

Is the G+ widget a custom one or is this some kind of hidden, undocumented, but standard style that I could also use for my own apps?

Just for clarification, I'm using a `@style/Theme.Sherlock` theme and have `targetApi` set to 17 (`minSdk` is 8).

Comment: Which Android version do you use?

Comment: targetApi is 17, minSdk is 8.

Answer (score 1):

Just my 5 cents that you use a not state-of-the-art Android version (around 2.x). The standard  progressbar-icon was once just "a thick circle", but nowadays (Android 3+) it is this wonderful, shiny circle. So what you get really depends on the Android OS version you are running your application on.

However, the Google+ app just copied the Android4 ProgressBar icon and added it to the local project, hence it is available everywhere.

Comment: On older devices (API 8) I see a different indicator even, one that comes closer to the iOS one that is broken down into several smaller pieces. So apparently something is wrong with my style settings then...? I derive from `@style/Theme.Sherlock` to provide API 8 compat  wrt the ActionBar. Is this to blame?